# Tomcat successfully registered in Netbeans but not chooseable

Tags: tomcat, netbeans

Tomcat 8.5 is successfully registered in Netbeans 8.2 and I can start Tomcat with Netbeans.
[image: Netbeans 8.2 starts Tomcat 8.5]

Xubuntu 16.04

Java Version is Oracle JDK 1.8.0_152.

/etc/profile

`export CATALINA_HOME=/home/allapow/Apps/apache-tomcat-8.5.27
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/Oracle_Java/jdk1.8.0_152`

~/Apps/netbeans-8.2/etc/netbeans.conf

`netbeans_jdkhome="/opt/Oracle_Java/jdk1.8.0_152"`

Problem: If I create a new JavaEE project, it tells me that there are no Tomcat registered. There is also no JavaEE version selectable.
[image: Netbeans 8.2 new Enterprise Application]

Why does this happen and what can I do to create a new JavaEE project in Netbeans?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to download GlassFish Server for this.
The download link for GlassFish server is [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/glassfish/downloads/index.html).
And the installation instructions are [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21454_01/html/821-2531/gknen.html).